# Find Regex Give more than one result

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a code that findme info for some URLs
How can i set this code for that only give me one string result?.
Actually this code bring me all results, I just need one.
In the image below the green rectangle is the correct result, but if the url contains the string more than one time this show me boths, red rectangle.

```
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    url = row['e.URL'].replace('/v01/', '/depot/')
    x = urlopen(url)
    new = x.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(new, "lxml-xml")
    match = ''.join(re.findall(r"(?i)cl[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{5}", str(soup)))
    df.at[idx,'NEW_APP'] = match
```

The below code brings me all results:

```
match = ''.join(re.findall(r"(?i)cl[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{5}", str(soup)))
```

See image below for reference:

[image: GREEN, CORRECT RESULT]

Comment: Change [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

Comment: Give me the below error:

Comment: ----> 6     match = ''.join(re.search(r"(?i)cl[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{5}", str(soup)))
TypeError: can only join an iterable

Comment: You can't join a single string on nothing. You would just return the match? `match = re.search(...)`

Comment: now i set the code like this:
match = (re.search(r"(?i)cl[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{5}", str(soup)))
but the result is something like this, i only need the code: <re.Match object; span=(3035, 3045), match='CLBAR10025'>

Comment: Add `if match:` before your `df.at[idx, 'NEW_APP'] = match` line and get the `0`th group

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to have multiple matches then you can use `re.search`.

```py
found = re.search(r"(?i)cl[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{5}", str(soup))
match = found.group(0) if found else ''
```

Or you can use the findall like you do now but only use the first match

```py
matches = re.findall(r"(?i)cl[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{5}", str(soup))
match = matches[0] if matches else ''
```